# Why does my program still run after adding semicolons after @end in implementation file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was messing around with xcode some, and found that if I add the following at the end of my .m files it does nothing:

```
@implementation ViewController 

@end
;
;
;
;
;
;
```

It didn't really matter how many of the semicolons I added. It still didn't affect the program in anyway. My initial guess was that at the "@end" of the implementation it quit reading all lines after "@end" and didn't affect anything at all; however, I tried adding just anything after that:

```
@implementation ViewController

@end

adsf
dafds
()
```

and it wouldn't let me run the program. I'm just curious that's all.

Comment: No, the compiler does not stop reading after the `@end`. You can have more than one `@implementation/@end` pair in a file.

Comment: Those are "empty statements" (or "null statements").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

semicolons wont affect your program at any place (by 'any' i mean after any command, not in the middle of it), not just after the `@end`.
if you write

```
int i;;;;
;;;
;;;
```

that will be ok too.
semicolon mark "end" of command, empty command is also ok, the compiler just ignores it

Answer (score 2):

Because the @end directive is only there to say that that's the end of the implementation of your class and you can still create stuff outside of it - like methods or global variables:

```
@end

bool lovesemicolon = true;;;;;

void derp() {
  ;;; // <3
}
```